# exception to domain forwarding

Tags: networking, dns, php, php5

I have forwarded a domain from a hosting site to our own http server. I would now like to host some pages directly on host server to take advantage of some of the services they have; for example - a mail form in html / php that uses the the hosting service's mail server. I still want the domain generally forwarded to our http server. How do I set that up?

The hosting service DNS panel allow me to create A Records, Web Alias, and CNAMEs among other things. I assume that this will be part of the solution. I don't know if I need to say much about my guesses at this point. But there would seem to be a need to like, sort-of "forward" an A Record back to the initial host or something like that, so that it is an exception to the rule that the domain is forwarded elsewhere. Am I warm? Should the A Record name match the name of a subdirectory where my pages are kept? (Ignore my guesses if this isn't the way it's done.)

UPDATE: I've added PHP tags hoping their might be a way to discover the IP address to use for the solution to this. See comments below.

Comment: You could create a subdomain A record that points to the IP of your hosting provider's web server - something like `app.mydomain.com` so anyone going to that full domain will get directed to your hosting web server and everything going to `www.mydomain.com` will go to your remote web server IP

Comment: OK, I've set up an A-Record mail.mydomain.com with "value" (typically an IP address to forward to) set to 127.0.0.1 - just something I found on the internet that says it refers to localhost and hope it's right. I'm now waiting the "up to 90 minutes" for the change to take effect. If I have a text file test.txt in my subdirectory mail, would I access it through a browser as mail.mydomain.com/test.txt ?

Comment: Be careful using `mail.` because if you have any email server capability on your hosting then this will use the `mail.` A record... You shouldn't use the IP 127.0.0.1 as your hosting web server will (undoubtedly) be on a different server than the control panel - your hosting should be able to tell you what your web server IP is...

Comment: That makes sense. I've changed it to wsmail. Unfortunately, the hosting service's chat was down today, but I sent them an email which will be answered sooner or later. I kind of thought they might need to answer that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not going to be easy to get the answer from the hosting company's tech. support. I just spent a half hour chatting online with someone who didn't understand the question. Meanwhile, I can go to stats.mydomain.com and get the stats for the website which is hosted on their server and not mine. Anyways - the site supports PHP and no console. If I turn off my redirect for www. might there be a way to run a PHP program through a browser that will give me the local IP? (Might that work?)

Comment: Because you've already redirected your `www.` you can't ping that because it'll show your "in-house" web server IP. Surely your web hosting control panel shows the IP of the web server they provide? That's all you need to know from them...

Comment: I can take the www. redirect off temporarily just for testing. Our advertised address doesn't use the www prefix and I'll do it if needed. The web hosting company gave me an assigned external IP. I've tried to simply use that in place of the domain name and simply get timed out: "The web page is not available." I also have a file system path: /customers/5/5/5/mysite.com//httpd.www/

Comment: I also have other accounts with the same hosting company. I can perform experiments with those, just to see what general works.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention - when I try to put the external address they gave me in as the A Record redirect value, I get an error message - must be a valid address ... I've tried CNAME and am now trying Web Alias (takes 90 minutes to become valid). Am I addressing things right in my tests? subname.mysite.com/subdir/file.txt ?

Comment: Your hosting company should be able to help you. The whole point of an A record is to be able to route your domain name "parts" to the correct IPs. For example your `www.` A record could go to `1.2.3.4`. You also probably have `mail.` which will go to `2.4.6.8`. You can also create new A records (say `myapp.`) to go to `4.3.2.1`. The last one here is what we concentrate on because this is your custom one and the `4.3.2.1` should be the web server IP that your hosting company originally created for you when you first signed up for hosting with them...